# Can not read DOM value, getting Vue.js template (in Chromium, both fom DevTools and extension)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a Chrome extension, which wants to read some values from the page, e.g. item title. But it reads not the actual title but some *Vue.js* template variable.

Even if I open DevTools, I can't get the value, only the template variable name.

```
> document.getElementsByClassName("page-title-text")[0]
​
<span class=​"page-title-text">​{{pageTitle}}​</span>​
```

On the webpage, I can see the actual title. Can I get the raw value somehow? Especially I need the `href` attribute of a link (tag `<a>`). I don't really want to use Vue.js in my extension, just get the value from DOM.

Answer (score 2):

> *Especially I need the href attribute of a link (tag `<a>`)*

You're looking for [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```js
console.log(
  ` a.getAttribute('href') => '${document
    .getElementsByClassName("foo")[0]
    .getAttribute("href")}'\n`,
  `span.getAttribute('class') => '${document
    .getElementsByTagName("span")[0]
    .getAttribute("class")}'`
);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="foo">foo</a>
<span class="page-title-text">bar</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, the site has tricked me.

```
> document.getElementsByClassName("page-title-text")[1]

<span class="page-title-text">The Real Title</span>
```

There is a hidden first element somewhere, which contains the template, that scared me, and also the empty value caused error, so my script has stopped.

Comment: One of the ways in which Vue components get rendered is by using `<template>` tags, which are valid DOM nodes. Even though they are only used for generating the component's HTML, much like a blueprint, they are part of DOM. Your script was selecting the first element in DOM with that class, which happened to be the one inside the template, not the actual component instance tag. You can filter out template descendants using `document.getElementsByClassName('example-class').filter(el => !el.closest('template'))`.